# How do i download a specific version of SQlite?

Tags: sql, windows, sqlite

Specifically I need this exact flavor of SQLite (3.7.16.2)?

I do see it mentioned on this page:

http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

but I don't see any steps for using this info:

SQLITE_SOURCE_ID: "2013-04-12 11:52:43 cbea02d93865ce0e06789db95fd9168ebac970c7"

SHA1 for sqlite3.c: d466b54789dff4fb0238b9232e74896deaefab94

I searched github for SQL, and found 100+ links but nothing looked legit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [SQLite download page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) at the bottom:

> **Build Product Names**
>
> Build products are named using one of the following templates:
>
> 1. **sqlite**-product-version.**zip**
> 2. **sqlite**-product-version.**tar.gz**
> 3. **sqlite**-product-os-cpu-version.**zip**
> 4. **sqlite**-product-date.**zip**
>
> Templates (1) and (2) are used for source-code products. Template (1)
>   is used for generic source-code products and templates (2) is used for
>   source-code products that are generally only useful on unix-like
>   platforms. Template (3) is used for precompiled binaries products.
>   Template (4) is used for unofficial pre-release "snapshots" of source
>   code.
>
> The version is encoded so that filenames sort in order of increasing
>   version number when viewed using "ls". For version 3.X.Y the filename
>   encoding is 3XXYY00. For branch version 3.X.Y.Z, the encoding is
>   3XXYYZZ.
>
> The date in template (4) is of the form: YYYYMMDDHHMM

So, I would look for `sqlite-<product>-3071602.zip`, `sqlite-<product>-<os>-<cpu>-3071602.zip` or `sqlite-<product>-201304121152.zip`.

The links on the website all go to http://www.sqlite.org/2014/, so I suspect you need to update the URL to the right year to find older releases, too.

For example:

http://www.sqlite.org/2013/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3071602.zip

http://www.sqlite.org/2013/sqlite-src-3071602.zip

Comment: Wow, that helps. Why don't they take the time to explain this on their own site. Is there a look up to know <product> translates to dll etc? At the very least they should change Build Product Names to Download Old Versions.

Comment: @AleksandrGembinski No lookup I know of, no. I think it's to discourage use of out-of-date versions. It's a programmer's (or engineer's) answer. You don't tell someone something. You don't tell someone how to do something. You tell them how to know how to do something. PITA, and extremely common in open source, IMX.